# How to choose a path to download a file using angularjs and send it to a java class?

Tags: java, html, angularjs

Currently I am using a java class to create and download a file. But now I need to let the user to select a path and send the path to relevant java class and download the created file there.
I think this can be done using angularjs. As I have developed my front end using angularjs and html.
But I couldn't find a proper way to do this as I am new to angularjs.
If someone could suggest me a tutorial or an idea, it'll be a big help.
Thank you.

Comment: If the end user is sending a file to an application running on a server, that is an upload operation, not a download operation.  Just to clarify:  is that the type of operation you are talking about?

Comment: No, he's not sending a file. I want to send the path as a string to the class which creates a text file and downloads it. I want to pass the user selected path here.